# Magento 1.9 - Price incl tax is adding tax again

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm working with an inherited site, and after changing the tax rules so it ensured that customers from the Channel Islands who chose the UK as their country were not charged tax `(using this method: http://www.jimcode.org/2011/08/guernsey-jersey-gstvat-rates-magento/ where it looks at the postcode as well)`, the site now calculates the catalog price incorrectly as it re-adds the tax onto the price. Eg. price in set in admin as £99.99 (incl tax), but on the frontend, it shows as £119.99 (incl tax).

**My settings are:**

```
  Magento Version: 1.9.1.0 
  Catalog prices: Including tax
  Tax Calculation Based On: Delivery Address
  Default Tax Destination Calculation Default Country: United Kingdom
  Enable Cross Border Trade: No
  Shipping Settings Origin Country: United Kingdom
```

On searching where people have had a similar problem, people say to change the shipping origin country, but my tax calculation needs to be based on the delivery address.

Even if I revert my tax rules to the previous default settings, it does not fix the problem. I've reindexed, cleared cache, resaved a product, resaved the config settings ... but can't get it working.

I'm thinking that perhaps there has been some sort of corruption maybe? `Do I need to run some sort of 'recalculate tax' perhaps?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the tax_calculation_rate table, one of the rows had NULL in the tax_postcode column. In my case, it needed to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In administration go to `settings > sales > tax > calculation` and set “tax based on” to the last item (package origin, or something like that; terms are not perfect).

Or you can change setting accordingly as you want in your cart.

If your code is perfect then you are just missing some configuration detail.

Also you can go throw all the inner tabs for tax calculation.

Comment: The 'tax calculation based on' is set as Delivery Address (or Shipping Address), so yes, when in the cart, the user can change their country to estimate shipping which recalculates the tax. Unfortunately, this still means that tax is added again for the product.
I don't know what you mean by "you can go throw all the inner tabs for tax calculation". What is this, and where do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Apply Customer Tax** Should be set to **Before Discount**

[image]